# How can I get Wireshark with a GUI on my EC2?

Tags: wireshark, yum, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon EC2 machine that I'd like to run Wireshark on, using X forwarding. Unfortunately, the only Wireshark packages found with `$ yum search wireshark` are:

```
wireshark-devel.x86_64
wireshark.i686
wireshark.x86_64
```

Some googling shows that I need the wireshark-gnome package.

I'm running `Amazon Linux AMI 2012.03`. Is it possible to get wireshark-gnome, using yum?

Comment: if you don't find a way, you could always capture some packets into a file with tshark and open the file on another machine with wireshark

Comment: @ColinPickard That's pretty much my current method :) It gets the job done, but I find it much easier to look at a live Wireshark capture than a live command line dump, or in Wireshark after the fact.

Comment: how about forwarding the packets over ssh to a local wireshark? http://www.howtoforge.com/wireshark-remote-capturing

Comment: @ColinPickard It worked! Well with a little fiddling. I had to change the permissions of tcpdump to 4755. I should also note that for those unfamiliar with tcpdump, the example from the link includes a capture filter (`port 53`) which you'll probably want to leave out. If you put this as an answer, I'll be happy to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you can [forward the packets over ssh](http://www.howtoforge.com/wireshark-remote-capturing) and view them live in a local copy of wireshark.  The command to do this (on your local machine) will look something like this:

```
wireshark -k -i <( ssh -l root probe /usr/sbin/tcpdump -i eth0 -w - )
```

Answer (score 0):

This command line working out of box with EC2 CentOS, if you are using Ubuntu just change the ec2-user to Ubuntu:

`wireshark -k -i <( ssh -t  -i private.pem ec2-user@ec2host "sudo /usr/sbin/tcpdump -i eth0 -w -"  )`